# When i try to resume JW Player video it starts at beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jwplayer

I have a video pause like below:

```
jwplayer('video').onTime(function(event){
                    if ((event.position >= 19 && event.position < 20) || (event.position >= 29 && event.position < 30)){
                        jwplayer('video').pause();
                        $(".container").fadeOut(300);
                    }
                });
```

Then my app hides the video's container whilst it does something else.
Later my app will show the container then attempt to resume it.

```
$(".container").show();
var currentPosition = Math.ceil(jwplayer('video').getPosition());
jwplayer('video').seek(currentPosition);
```

For some strange reason the video will start from the beginning. Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

If i use console and try:

```
$(".container").show();
```

It seems to be restarting. I believe the "show" is causing it to start again.

I have narrowed down the problem a bit. When jquery changes display from none to block (as part of show method) the video restarts.

Comment: Instead of seeking, try calling `.pause(false)` to resume playing. My guess would be that getting the position while the player is paused may not work.

Comment: I tried it already with a demo. It should work. I believe this issue has something to do with jQuery hide and show.

Comment: Have you tried calling it from the completion callback of `show`? `$('.container').show(400, function() { jwplayer('video').pause(false) });`

Comment: I just tried that and i get the same problem. I have narrowed down the problem a bit. When jquery changes display from none to block (as part of show) the video restarts.

Comment: Hm, do you have an example of where you are running this? You might be able to just hide and show it with CSS, setting the visibility to hidden, instead of display=none to display=block.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and get back to you with an example if it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which is a combination of a few ideas.
If i set the video's autostart property to false and then manually start the video it seems to fix part of the problem.

```
jwplayer('quest-video').setup({
            file: $("#quest-video").text(),
            title: 'Quest for the Golden Shield',
            width: '1000',
            height: '535',
            controls: 'false',
            fallback: 'false',
            mute: 'true',
            autostart: 'false'
        });

 jwplayer('quest-video').play();
```

Then when i hide and show it by setting the visibility to hidden etc it does not restart.

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 3):

Might be easier to store the resume position in a variable accessible from both places and see if bypassing `getPosition` resolves your issues

```
var resume_position = 0;
jwplayer('video').onTime(function(event){
    if ((event.position >= 19 && event.position < 20) || (event.position >= 29 && event.position < 30)){
        resume_position = event.position;
        jwplayer('video').pause();
        $(".container").fadeOut(300);
    }
});

...


$(".container").show();
jwplayer('video').seek(resume_position);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work for me. Thanks anyway.